# Skew Data with countDistinct

Tags: pyspark, skew

I have a PySpark DataFrame with 3 columns: 'client', 'product', 'date'. I want to run a groupBy operation:

```
df.groupBy("product", "date").agg(F.countDistinct("client"))
```

So I want to count the number of clients that bought a product in each day. This is causing huge skew data (in fact, it causes error because of memory). I have been learning about salting techniques. As I understood, it can be used with 'sum' or 'count' adding a new column to the groupBy and performing a second aggregation, but I do not see how to apply them in this case because of the `countDistinct` aggregation method.

How can I do apply it in this case?

Comment: Does the date contain hours and minutes?

Comment: No, only year-month-day

Comment: @RodrigoSernaPérez , could you please clarify whether my answer helped to resolve the issue? Or maybe some comment if it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to just not use `countDistinct` at all here and achieve what you want using 2 aggregations in a row especially since you have a skew in your data. It can look like the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
new_df = (df
  .groupBy("product", "date", "client")
  .agg({}) # getting unique ("product", "date", "client") tuples
  .groupBy("product", "date")
  .agg(F.count('*').alias('clients'))
)
```

First aggregation here ensures that you have a DataFrame with one row per each distinct ("product", "date", "client") tuple, second is counting number of clients for each ("product", "date") pair. This way you don't need to worry about skews anymore since Spark will know to do partial aggregations for you (as opposed to `countDistinct` which is forced to send all individual "client" values corresponding to each ("product", "date") pair to one node).